# Disappearing program thumbnail on taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-8, mouse, taskbar, thumbnails

I have a problem - when I hover mouse on icon of program/folder in taskbar, then the thumbnail shows, and when I hover mouse on the thumbnail, all that program's thumbnail disappears, and current hover folder or program got on all screen, but does not become active.

Before on hover program/folder I get all that type opened thumbnails and could drive on them with the mouse until press left mouse button. But now they dissapear on hover.

I googled for problem, and there was possible solutions that change value to variable `ActiveWindowsTracking` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER->Control Panel->Mouse`, but there all was correct.
And second solution that disable `Activate the window by hovering over it with mouse` in `Control Panel -> Ease Acces Center -> Make the mouse easier, but it did not help too.

Here's an example:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeeah! I found a solution for me.
Problem was in software `Kaspersky Antivirus`. I've installed that programm few days ago, and it's disabled default `Windows Defender`. So i tryed to delete `kaspersky`, and enabled back `windows defender`, restart my PC and problemm has gone.
I dont know how and why that programm affected to windows in taskbar, but removing that programm helped me. :) Mby `kaspersky`decided that some system files, which resposible for displaying that thunbnails in taskbar, for virus and throw them in to the quarantine, but i didn't get any notifications.

I don't want to say that that antivirus is bad, nope, he helped me to found many malicious programs, but removing them helped to me. Thanks.